# Can I upload files in bzip2 to storage and then use them in bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a bunch of (largish, 10GB each) files in `bz2` format. I would like to upload them and then perform some queries on them. Does big query "understand" bzip as it does gzip? Should I convert them? What would be the best way to upload them?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the files are in CSV or JSON format. Per BigQuery documentation (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/preparing-data-for-loading), only `gzip` compression is supported. Bit even if `bz2` was supported, it wouldn't be a good idea to work with 10GB sized compressed files. The problem is that unlike with uncompressed file - BigQuery won't be able to split them into pieces, and will have to work with entire 10GB file, which will be very slow.

Comment: Do you think it would be faster to create a Table from an uncompressed `CSV` file rather than from a compressed `gz` file?