# Google BigQuery: After changing folder structure in G Storage, why is creating GBQ Table much slower?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

In Google Storage, I had a folder structure like:

```
my_bucket---+--file_1.gz      # 1MB
            |
            +--file_2.gz      # 1MB
            |
            +--file_3.gz      # 1MB
            |
            +--file_5.gz      # 1MB
            |
            +-- ...
```

this folder structure contained 50,000 files. To create a new table in Google BigQuery using my_bucket would take me a few minutes. Then I thought I would change the folder structure to:

```
my_bucket---+--all_files.gz      # 50 GB
```

And now when I use the same process to create the job, it takes me about 2 hours. What is going on here?

The reason that I changed this to this folder structure is that I will be doing daily uploads to my_bucket and I want to have fewer individual files, so before I upload to Storage I will merge all my `csv` files into one big `csv` file and then compress it into a `gz` files. When I am done uploading and ready to create the table by rerunning a job like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHO9T.jpg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if joining all files into a single one is a good approach to load data into BigQuery. As you can see in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747415/can-i-upload-files-in-bzip2-to-storage-and-then-use-them-in-bigquery/44748845#44748845) from Mosha, BigQuery does not parallel read a compressed file.

That'd explain why it's taking 2 hours in your case for the job to finish.

Still, I wonder why it would be a problem having several files inside of a GCS folder. Since they are all located in the same path, it works like a compressed file with several smaller parts inside of the same folder.

Comment: It is probably a problem because the first `gz` file in each folder is like 10GB large and Mosha said that compressed files are not read in parallel. I wonder if I should load all the files in their uncompressed form to speed things up. Do you think a 50 GB `csv` would be read faster than a 10 GB `gz` file?

Comment: Don't know, it would have to be tested. Still, it looks like the best approach is keeping several compressed small files for the job and not having any big files (compressed or not).

Comment: Google seems to encourage the data being uncompressed for faster loads: "If loading speed is important to your app and you have a lot of bandwidth to load your data, leave your files uncompressed." stated on [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/preparing-data-for-loading) page.

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to test to see how it works for you (keep in mind that there'll be trade-offs such as higher bills for storage and bandwidth consumption so you'd have to choose that only if loading speed is an issue)

Comment: Thanks, I understand that storage will cost more but I never saw any google charges/documentation for "higher bandwidth"... would I be paying Google or my ISP?

Comment: it's your internet connection sending data to GCS